# Regex for optional end-part of substring

Tags: regex, string, python-3.x

Consider the following (highly simplified) string:

```
'a b a b c a b c a b c'
```

This is a repeating pattern of `'a b c'` except at the beginning where the `'c'` is missing.

I seek a regular expression which can give me the following matches by the use of  `re.findall()`:

```
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c')]
```

The string above thus have 4 matches of `'a b c'` - although with the first match as a special case since the `'c'` is missing.

My simplest attempt is where I try to capture `'a'` and `'b'` and use an optional capture for `'c'`:

```
re.findall(r'(a).*?(b).*?(c)?', 'a b a b c a b c a b c')
```

I get:

```
[('a', 'b', ''), ('a', 'b', ''), ('a', 'b', ''), ('a', 'b', '')]
```

Clearly, it has just ignored the `c`. When using non-optional capture for `'c'` the search skips ahead prematurely and misses `'a'` and `'b'` in the second `'a b c'`-substring. This results in 3 wrong matches:

```
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c')]
```

I have tried several other techniques (for instance, `'(?<=c)'`) to no avail.

Note: The string above is just a skeleton example of my "real-world" problem where the three letters above are themselves strings (from a long log-file) in between other strings and newlines from which I need to extract named groups.

I use Python 3.5.2 on Windows 7.

Comment: You need to remove the empty tuple elements "manually" after `re.findall` does its job.

Comment: Are you sure that you need regexes to parse your logs?

Comment: @WayneWerner Yes :) Absolutely necessary.

Comment: Your example is so simplified that it makes it hard to provide a solid answer.  I believe the problem lies with your use of the `.*?` wildcard in between a, b, and c. For starters, try using `.+?` instead so that the lazy operator doesn't cause it to match zero characters and start the pattern over again.

Comment: No, the problem can't be solved with a regex nor with regex methods. Use comprehension and build the final list by removing empty elements from tuples.

Comment: This regex format works in R `^ab|abc`

Example:
`x = "ababcabcabc"`
`stringr::str_extract_all(x,"^ab|abc")`
`[1] "ab" "abc" "abc" "abc"`

Not sure how that is implemented in python.

Comment: The above R code does not solve the current issue. The point is that if a pattern has 3 capture groups defined, `re.findall` will return a list of 3-element tuples, whether they got initialized or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `a`, `b`, and `c` are *placeholders*, and you cannot know if those are single characters, or character sequences, or anything else, you need to use a *tempered greedy token* to make sure the pattern does not overflow to the other matches in the same string, and since the `c` is optional, just wrap it with a `(?:...)?` optional non-capturing group:

```
(a)(?:(?!a|b).)*(b)(?:(?:(?!a|b|c).)*(c))?
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vH7bT9/1)

**Details**:

- `(a)` - Group 1 capturing some `a`
- `(?:(?!a|b).)*` - a tempered greedy token matching any char not starting  a `a` or `b` sequences
- `(b)` - Group 2 capturing some `b`
- `(?:` - start of an optional non-capturing group, repeated 1 or 0 times

  - `(?:(?!a|b|c).)*` - a tempered greedy token that matches any char but a newline that starts a `a`, `b` or `c` pattern
  - `(c)` - Group 3 capturing some `c` pattern
- `)?` - end of the optional non-capturing group.

To obtain the tuple list you need, you need to build it yourself using comprehension:

```
import re
r = r'(a)(?:(?!a|b).)*(b)(?:(?:(?!a|b|c).)*(c))?'
s = 'a b a b c a b c a b c'
# print(re.findall(r,s))
# That one is bad: [('a', 'b', ''), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c')]
print([(a,b,c) if c else (a,b) for a,b,c in re.findall(r,s)])
# This one is good: [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c')]
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/jQ9fXX)

Comment: Thanks. Regular expressions are good for simple things (at least). What I am trying to do cannot, I think, be done by finite state machine rules (it requires more branching logic it seems). I have just tried your approach and it still misses parts. I will seek another approach. Accepted because I learned something new :-)

Comment: Well, you only posted very simplified sample that I tried to generalize as most as I could. Regexps require precision and need exact precise requirements anx specifications. Best regards.